# How do I install libDb from source on OSX

Tags: c, automake

I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/berkeleydb/libdb) and then...

```
cd build_unix
../dist/configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then I go to the project I am trying to compile and run `stack install` I get the following...

```
Configuring BerkeleyDB-0.8.7...
    Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2: Missing dependency on a foreign
    library:
    * Missing C library: db
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

This is on OSX

Answer (score 0):

Rather than compiling from source, you could use homebrew:

```
brew install berkeley-db
```

Comment: This didn't ask using homebrew. Notice the "from source"